# How to I find external 404s

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm building a scraper with scrapy that should crawl an entire domain looking for broken EXTERNAL links.

I have the following:

```
class domainget(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'getdomains'
    allowed_domains = ['start.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.start.co.uk']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor('/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny = self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
            resp = scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_ext)


    def parse_ext(self, response):
        self.logger.info('>>>>>>>>>> Reading: %s', response.url)
```

When I run this code, it never reaches the parse_ext() function where I would like to get the http status code and do further processing based on this.

You can see I have used parse_ext() as the callback when I'm looping the extracted links on the page in the parse_item() func.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the `Request` instances from the callback:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny = self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
        yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_ext)

def parse_ext(self, response):
    self.logger.info('>>>>>>>>>> Reading: %s', response.url)
```

Comment: Bingo! Also, I had to add in dont_filter=True into the Request object like so: 

yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_ext, dont_filter=True)